# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext cannot be cast to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext

Tags: java, dependency-injection, log4j

I'm trying to create SpellChecker program through API. Here is my code:

**SpellCheck.java**

```
package com.spell;

import org.xeustechnologies.googleapi.spelling.SpellChecker;
import org.xeustechnologies.googleapi.spelling.SpellCorrection;
import org.xeustechnologies.googleapi.spelling.SpellResponse;

public class SpellCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        SpellChecker checker = new SpellChecker();

        SpellResponse spellResponse = checker.check( "helloo worlrd" );

        for( SpellCorrection sc : spellResponse.getCorrections() ) 
            System.out.println( sc.getValue() );

    }
}
```

**Dependencies**

[image]

[image]

**Error I got after running it:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
> at com.spell.SpellCheck.main(SpellCheck.java:12)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext cannot be cast to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext
> at org.apache.log4j.Logger$PrivateManager.getContext(Logger.java:59)
> at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:41)
> at org.xeustechnologies.googleapi.spelling.SpellChecker.(SpellChecker.java:50)
> ... 1 more

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the `org.xeustechnologies.googleapi.spelling.SpellChecker` API.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `org.xeustechnologies.google.api.spelling.SpellChecker` uses log4j and you are using slf4j.  Try adding [log4j-over-slf4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j) to the classpath to bridge log4 to use slf4j.

Comment: After removing all log4j jars,i've added only 2 jars(api-spell checker,log4j-over-slf4j-1.7) but after running the program i got these errors:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/MarkerFactory
 at org.apache.log4j.Category.<clinit>(Category.java:53)
 at org.xeustechnologies.googleapi.spelling.SpellChecker.<clinit>(SpellChecker.java:50)
 at com.spell.SpellCheck.main(SpellCheck.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.MarkerFactory at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: Looks like you haven't got the slf4j API on your classpath. Add slf4j-api.jar.